# Manipulating and printing items in a python dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following code:

```
ex_dict={1:"how",3:"do you",7:"dotoday"}
for key in ex_dict:
    string= key," and this is ", ex_dict[key]
    print (string)
```

The output is:

```
(1, ' and this is ', 'how')
(3, ' and this is ', 'do you')
(7, ' and this is ', 'dotoday')
```

My intended output:

```
1 and this is how
3 and this is do you
7 and this is dotoday
```

I can't seem to figure out how to get rid of the dictionary formatting in my output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `+` to combine strings:

```
string = str(key) + " and this is " + ex_dict[key]
```

Since `key` is an integer, and you can only concatenate strings using the `+` operator, you should convert `key` to string as well.

Comment: oh.. well that's embarrassing.. so when I do it using commas, it means it will add (sort of) an entry into the list?

Comment: The comma operator is used to define a tuple. See https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences

Comment: Commas are used to define a tuple. As you discovered, the parentheses in `string = (key, " and this is ", ex_dict[key])` are optional. Note that their use in the Python 2 `print` statement are part of that statement's syntax, and not the tuple constructor.

Answer (score 3):

You're not looking at dictionary formatting, you're looking at [tuples](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TupleSyntax).

> In Python, multiple-element tuples look like:
>
> `1,2,3`
>
> The essential elements are the commas between each element of the tuple. Multiple-element tuples may be written with a trailing comma, e.g.
>
> `1,2,3,`
>
> but the trailing comma is completely optional. Just like all other expressions in Python, multiple-element tuples may be enclosed in parentheses, e.g.
>
> `(1,2,3)`
>
> or
>
> `(1,2,3,)`

Use string formatting instead:

```
ex_dict={1:"how",3:"do you",7:"dotoday"}
for key in ex_dict:
    print("{} and this is {}".format(key,ex_dict[key]))
```

**Additionally:** You can simplify your code with

```
ex_dict={1:"how",3:"do you",7:"dotoday"}
for key, val in ex_dict.iteritems(): #ex_dict.items() in python3
    print("{} and this is {}".format(key,val))
```

**Finally:** be forewarned that dictionaries in python have [arbitrary order.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479928/why-is-the-order-in-python-dictionaries-and-sets-arbitrary) If you want your ordering to be always the same, it's safer to use [collections.OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict). Because otherwise, you're depending on implementation detail. Want to see it for yourself? Make `ex_dict = {1:"how",3:"do you",7:"dotoday", 9:"hi"}`.

```
import collections
ex_dict= collections.OrderedDict([(1,"how"),(3,"do you"),(7,"dotoday")])
for key, val in ex_dict.iteritems(): #ex_dict.items() in python3
    print("{} and this is {}".format(key,val))
```

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
string= key," and this is ", ex_dict[key]
```

with

```
string= str(key) + " and this is " + ex_dict[key]
```

in python you concat  string with + not with ,

, is used for tuples

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
string= key," and this is ", ex_dict[key]
```

with

```
string= str(key) +" and this is "+ ex_dict[key]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.join` and `str.format` which is more readable and less prone to simple errors:

```
ex_dict = {1: "how",3: "do you",7: "dotoday"}
print("\n".join(["{} and this is {}".format(*tup) 
                for tup in ex_dict.items()]))
```

Output:

```
1 and this is how
3 and this is do you
7 and this is dotoday
```

Or using python3 or with `from __future__ import print_function` with python2, you can unpack and use the sep keyword:

```
ex_dict = {1: "how", 3: "do you", 7: "dotoday"}
print(*("{} and this is {}".format(*tup) 
        for tup in ex_dict.items()), sep="\n")
```

Output:

```
1 and this is how
3 and this is do you
7 and this is dotoday
```